# Initialize the value of a textbox when form loads

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I would like to put a string value in my `frmCredentials.txtUsername` text box when the form first loads.

Here is the code where the form is first called:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new frmCredentials());
```

Comment: what's the problem then ?

Answer (score 4):

Why not put the code in the [Form.Load event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx)

> Occurs before a form is displayed for the first time.
>
> You can use this event to perform tasks such as allocating resources used by the form.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an overloaded constructor that accepts one parameter, and another one will be your default constructor.

```
public class frmCredentials : Form
{
    public frmCredentials()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public frmCredentials(string myValue )
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtUsername.Text = myValue;
    }
}
```

from your code:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new frmCredentials("Hello World"));
```

Answer (score 2):

> Step 1) Double Click On Your Form: This will create and display the form load event.
>
> Step 2) Type in the {} the following, `txtUsername.Text="MyTextGoesHere";`

After you try this if this still does not resolve your homework please comment below and I will try to help further.

Answer (score 2):

Yes Form load event is better to load default values when loading the Form

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtUsername.Text = "My Username";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set it in the constructor of frmCredentials:

```c#
public class frmCredentials : Form
{
    public frmCredentials()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        txtUsername.Text = "whatever";
    }
}
```

Comment: that's setting the value of the text box on instantiation of the class

Answer (score 1):

Mohit probably has the best answer, but if you ONLY want to be able to create a form with the textbox you don't need to retain the 'default' constructor as he/she did:

```
 public class frmCredentials : Form
 {
     public frmCredentials(string myValue)
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         txtUsername.Text = myValue;
     }
 }
```

Now when you call a new frmCredentials, you'll **have** to pass it a string, like so

```
 var myForm = new frmCredentials("A string is required.");
```